# how to add an array field in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have a model in `Sequelize` that communicates with my `MySQL` database. The model is defined below.

```
module.exports= (sequelize, DataTypes)=>{


const Form =  sequelize.define(
    "form",
    {   
        id:{
            type:DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull:false,
            autoIncrement:true,
            primaryKey:true,
            field:"id"
        },
        name:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING(20),
            unique:true,
            field:"title"

        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            field: "createdAt"
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            field: "updatedAt"
        },
        
        description:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING(300),
            allowNull: true,
            field:"description"
        },  
        questionId:{
            type:DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER),
            allowNull:true,
            field:"questionId"
        },
        userId_FK:{
            type:DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull:false,
            field:"userId_FK"
        }
    },
    {
        tableName:"form"
    }    
);

Form.associate = function(models){
    Form.belongsTo(models.user,{
        foreignKey : "userId_FK",
        onDelete : "CASCADE"
    });
};
return Form;};
```

As you can see there is an `ARRAY` field in the model defined. How can I add this field in my `MySQL` database by using a create table method, eg `create table 'form' (....)`.If there is another alternative please let me know.

Comment: MySQL does not implements ARRAY datatype. You may use JSON array (the column of JSON datatype) if it is safe for you. If the array elements are unsigned integers you may even create multivalued index by such column.

Answer (score 0):

There is no array field in MySQL, the solution I use is before sending the array to the DB I turn it into string and save it as string in the string field in the DB.

If you are thinking about switching to PostgreSQL there you can use PickleTypes to store data as something simillar to an array.

Comment: Ok so do i just add a string field for 'questionId' for my example and then insert the array under that column?

Comment: Yes what you would do is make the field a string, then when sending the JSON object in the backend simply type yourdata.toString() and that will be it